# Using a batch file to return a password from a text file in a stored variable

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Have been away from programming for a little while but now finding myself needing to automate some things. Essentially what I would like to do is have the batch file search the local directory for the file named "(U) Password.txt," which consists of 4 lines of string. I want it to search using "findstr" the word, "TEXT," and save skip to the next line capturing that line in a variable to use for the decryption password. The remaining code has been tested and works ok but plenty of room for improvement. Can I use "Skip=1" to capture the line under the market "Text" with findstr to capture the next line?

::Sample Code

```
     @ECHO OFF
REM version 0.4

:: Get the Current Directory ::
SET FolderName=%cd%

:: Make the new Encrypted and Unencrypted Folders
echo D| md %FolderName%\'Encrypted_Databases'
echo D| md %FolderName%\'Unencrypted_Databases'
echo D| md %FolderName%\'Difference_Reports'

set findtext="TEXT"
set findfile="(U) Password.txt"
findstr %findtext% %findfile%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr %findtext% %findfile%') do echo %%a

:: Decrypt the Databases ::
SET /p DB_PASSWORD= %%a
IF ["%DB_PASSWORD%"]==[""] ECHO Password not set. & GOTO EXIT
SET "DB_FILES=db1.db db2.db db3.db db4.db db5.db db6.db db7.db db8.db db9.db"

ECHO Decrypting...
SET /a DB_TOTAL_COUNT=0
for %%a in (%DB_FILES%) do (
  decryptionSoftware.exe -key "%DB_PASSWORD%" %%a "PRAGMA rekey='';"
  SET /a DB_TOTAL_COUNT+=1
)
ECHO Done!

ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Testing...
SET /a DB_COUNT=0
3>nul 2>nul (
  for %%b in (%DB_FILES%) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('decryptionSoftware.exe %%b "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SQLITE_MASTER;"') do (
      REM The following line will not execute if the SQLite command above fails
      SET /a DB_COUNT+=1
    )
  )
)
IF %DB_COUNT%==%DB_TOTAL_COUNT% ECHO Success decrypting!
IF %DB_COUNT% LSS %DB_TOTAL_COUNT% ECHO Problem decrypting!

::EXIT ::
ECHO.
ECHO.

: Move Unencrypted Databases from the Root Directory to the newly Created Unencrypted File Structure ::
echo F| XCOPY "%folderName%\DatabaseTesting\Unencrypted_Databases\*.db"/Y

PAUSE
exit
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? "need the string "Text" to be used to set my search location. Need the line under it."?

Comment: It is not very clear as to what specifically your problem is. Your question appears more like "here is some code, please fix it".

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry for the delay. I am looking through a text file for a string called "Text." I am wanting to take the line under this and use it as a variable in later code. The issue is that I can find Text and return it to the variable but cannot get the line under it as that text will change depending on the file that I am reading. I will need to use "Text" as a marker to find the line beneath.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a real world example of what the password text file looks like.

Comment: You have a lot of problems with your code besides reading that text file.

Comment: @Squashman Im sure. I have been away from Coding for a very long time. Do some Arduino stuff here and there but have some experiences but mostly C++, C# from years ago.

Comment: @StephenD.Dunn, I am not understanding the example you provided. Could you please go back into your question and edit your question so that it displays correctly.  It shows you a preview below when you are creating and editing your questions.

Comment: ::Sample Text Document::

::Begin::
UNCLASSIFIED

TEXT 4.0
**************

UNCLASSIFIED
::EOF

Comment: Please edit your post and include this information. It's very helpful to better understanding the question.

Comment: @StephenD.Dunn, sorry but you are going to have to learn how to edit your question to get the formatting correctly within your question.  I certainly cannot tell from your comment what the text file looks like.

Comment: I reread your question because you edited it some more.  Is the password always the third line?

Comment: Actually the password is the 4th line always. I am using 3rd line as a marker to locate the line beneath as the password will always change. The password is always the fourth line. @EricF I am not looking for anyone to fix my code for me I am looking for a recommendation for how to use the "Text" as a marker and get the line underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I am doing this right this actually might solve my problem. Instead of searching for the word "Text" in the file I can just search for line 4 in the file spaces and all. So this is my fix I think. Anyone think there is a better way?

```
@echo off
:: Exctract the Code from the Text Document ::
FOR /F "USEBACKQ SKIP=3" %%C IN ("(U) password.txt") DO ECHO %%C
```

Comment: With this I am storing the value in string into the Variable %%C and using that to pass the String for the password into the decryption line of code.

Comment: So now you are saying it is the last line in the file?